# How to return empty IEnumerable from expression-bodied member

Tags: c#, enumerable

Imagine you have to implement interface required property:

```
IEnumerable<int> Ids { get; }
```

which (implemented) returns empty enumeration.
You may write:

```
public IEnumerable<int> Ids
{
    get { yield break; }
}
```

But is there a way how to use expression bodied member syntax, so you may have this on single line?

Comment: `public IEnumerable<int> Ids => Enumerable.Empty<int>();` actually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `Enumerable.Empty<type>` function.

```
IEnumerable<int> Ids => Enumerable.Empty<int>();
```